# Do the first two encounters in the ruins count for the speedrun genocide route in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

In particular, I'm curious about two fights - the initial fight against the Dummy that Toriel has you fight, and the first encounter with Napstablook.

To stay on track for this route, do I need to kill Napstablook...

> Well, sort of - do I need to deplete his health? He can't actually be killed, rather you deplete his health and he leaves.

...and the dummy, or can I mercy these two for speedrun purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. Neither the dummy nor Napstablook count. It is faster to use Act->Talk on the dummy, and to grind all encounters in the three rock room before Napstablook: if you have already exhausted the encounters in RUINS by the time you meet Napstablook, he will simply fade away.

Comment: Apparently I was completely and utterly wrong the first time. This has been updated to reflect the reality

Answer (score -3):

you can just spare those two. fighting napstablook actually gets you negative EXP, as well as taking time, so he's better avoided.

Comment: If you "kill" Napstablook you lose an *experience* point. EXP is not that.